# AppleScript Custom Handler Syntax

Tags: applescript, handler

I am starting to learn AppleScript.  I am running into a couple issues that I could not find document for.

```
script gt
  to sms to someone about m
    "sms to " & someone & " about " & m
  end

  to move pix to pos
    "moving " & pix & " to " & pos
  end

  to resize in pix to size
    "resize " & pix & " to " & size
  end
end
```

1. for the to sms handler,  I have to add the "to" after the sms. 
   but I did not see any document mention the to as part of the
   directParamName
2. for the to move handler, it does not seem like
   the directParameter need either of, in or even "to"
3. for the to
   resize handler, I have to add either "in" or "of", or it won't work.
   if I add "to", it will complain "to" is used twice.

my question is why the "to sms" handler can have the "to", "to resize" handler must have either "in or of" while the "to move" handler needs none of these?

Thanks!

[Here is the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH7g-SW2) I read a couple times but could not find any reference to any of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically labeled parameters must contain a preposition and an argument.

Direct parameters are indicated by keyword `of` or `in`. In this case at least one parameter must follow. The documentation says

> *directParamName*
>
> An identifier for the direct parameter variable. If it is included,
>
> *directParamName* must be listed immediately after the command name. The
>   word `of` or `in` before *directParamName* is required in user-defined
>   handlers, but is optional in terminology-defined handlers (for
>   example, those defined by applications).
>
> If a user-defined handler includes a direct parameter, the handler
>   must also include at least one variable parameter.

Regarding your notes:

1. The preposition `to` as a labeled parameter is not documented but seems to work.
2. `move` is a reserved word of the Standard Suite and expects itself particular parameters. Do not use `move` as a handler name.
3. follows the rule about direct parameter. `size` could be also a reserved word depending on the installed Scripting Additions.

Actually Script Editor shows by syntax coloring the kind of a word. Green words can be safely used as variable names.

Comment: I just tried "on" preposition and it seems to work ok too.:  "to resize on pix ...".